# is it possible to launch android app by long press on/off button

Tags: android

i am developing an android app for blind people. 
I am searching for a way to run this app without pressing icons on screen.
I searched a lot but nothing helpful. there are some launcher apps do .
is there a way or an idea which help?

Comment: "I am searching for a way to run this app without pressing icons on screen" -- the BACK button is an icon on the screen for millions upon millions of devices.

Comment: i can use the on/off button